# parallelStream() submitted to ThreadPool vs ForkJoinPool?

Tags: java

There are lots of places explaining why you generally should use parallelStream() with an encompassing ForkJoinPool. However, do you have to use a ForkJoinPool or can you use any ExecutorService?

```
ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(4);
    forkJoinPool.submit(
      () -> aList.parallelStream().forEach(some parallel activity));
```

vs

```
ExecutorService cachedThreadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    cachedThreadPool.submit(
      () -> aList.parallelStream().forEach(some parallel activity));
```

Comment: Not sure I understand why it would be necessarily preferable to parallel stream instead of sequential stream a collection just because it's used by the runnable submitted in a ForkJoinPool in the first place. I'd say the only dichotomy is whether you want to stream it in parallel or sequentially in your runnable, regardless of how you submit your runnable to an execution pool - could you add some reference to the initial assumption?

Comment: If you use parallelStreams, it's usually a good idea to wrap it in a custom ForkJoinPool so it doesn't use the common ForkJoinPool. It'll then use the encompassing custom pool for its threading. My question is whether it has to be wrapped in a ForkJoinPool or if any executor will work similarly. https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-parallel-streams-are-bad-for-your-health/